# How to unlock new animals in Tokyo Jungle

Tags: tokyo-jungle

The way to unlock new animals in Tokyo Jungle is not clear to me.

For the animals, when putting the cursor over a locked animal, it says you have to achieve a given challenge, but how to find details about this challenge and what has to be done to unlock the given animal? I unlocked cats but I don't know how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am playing the English version of the game.  To unlock most of the animals you have to complete challenges.  These challenges appear at the bottom of the challenge list while playing Survival mode.  Most of the animals unlock 1 animal via the aforementioned challenge.  Some unlock 2, and a few (4 I think) of the animals unlocked this way don't unlock any further animals (the chimp and the second dinosaur don't unlock any (that's as far as I've gotten on those unlock trees)).  The robot dogs seem to be unlocked via getting the true ending of the story.

Answer (score 1):

The majority have to be unlocked through the different challenges. In the game, you can see the challenges by hitting the START button on the controller and then X when the Challenge List is highlighted, or flashing.

Others can be bought as DLC, and they include: two other Pomeranians, Panda, Saber Cat, Giraffe, Fat Cat (larger, stronger version of the cat), Silky Terrier, Crocodile. A few more can be unlocked by completing Story mode, or getting them through one of the various ones mentioned that can be bought. Each time you unlock the ones via challenge completion, it uses your survival points. Some of the animals have various colorations or other genders (such as the cats with color variants and Blackbucks with gender choices). Some stop after a certain point, meaning it doesn't move on to another animal such as the Chimpanzee, one of the dinosaurs (can't remember its name) and the Polar Bear.